# STS + Roo maven fail

Tags: spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I can't run any of the "perform" commands from the STS Roo Shell.

I keep getting:

```
~.web roo> perform package
error=2, No such file or directory
```

If I go to a non-STS shell, everyting works properly.

OS: Mac OSX 10.10
STS: 3.6.1.RELEASE
ROO: 1.2.5.RELEASE [rev 8341dc2]

Comment: I tried the STS Roo Shell a moment ago and this command seems to work for me. I created a new Roo project, ran the clinic script to populate my project with something meaningful, and executed the perform package command. It is doing a lot of stuff, but it seems to run fine. Can you try this on your machine as well? Would be interesting to see whether it is a problem with your installation or the project.

Comment: No luck.

1. I created a new project and ran the clinic script (as in the "1.6. Exploring the Roo Samples" http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/intro.html)
2. Imported the project into STS as a Maven project.
3. Tried "perform tests" / "perform package" etc... 

Same error.

Comment: Did you try to create the project as a Spring Roo project inside of STS and ran the script from inside of STS? In my tests, I never did anything outside of STS. Maybe that is causing an issue (when importing the Roo project as a Maven project).

Comment: I get the same result if I create a new ROO project via the STS IDE. I can't create from a ROO shell in STS because the ROO shell needs to be assigned to a project first.

Comment: Can you provide detailed steps how to reproduce the issue starting from a fresh STS installation? I can create a new Roo project using the "New Spring Roo Project" wizard inside STS (after installing the Roo extensions, of course), and then perform the commands in the Roo shell. What exactly do you do differently?

Comment: I don't do anything differently from you. New install, install Roo extensions, create a Roo project, open Roo shell and perform xxx. Fail.

Comment: I am now able to reproduce this error, but it seems to occur when running on OSX 10.10 only. The command is being executed on OSX 10.9.5. I opened an issue to track this: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3937

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Martin, I'm glad I'm not going crazy :) Wonder why my question was down-voted... :\

Comment: no idea about the downvote...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have Maven installed correctly on your machine. Open terminal then `mvn -v` to test Maven installation.